Excitability of the FitzHugh-Nagumo model
I have the following variant of the FitzHugh-Nagumo model:
$$\dot{u} = u - u^3 - v \\ \dot{v} = \epsilon(u-a)$$
Where $\epsilon>0$ and $a$ is a constant. 
I need to give a value for $a$ such that when $\epsilon \ll1$, we get an excitable system, and identify two initial conditions, such that one results in an immediate convergence to the stationary state, and the other that can result in excitation. 
I'm having difficulty understanding what makes a system "excitable" (I couldn't find a definite mathematical definition), and I have no idea how to show excitability here. I would appreciate if you could help me understand what to do here.

I suspect "excitable" in this context indicates the existence of a limit cycle. (Compare the simpler Van der Pol oscillator, which is itself a special case of the FitzHugh-Nagumo model.)

A system is called excitable if it has a linearly stable fixed-point solution, such that sufficiently small perturbations about this solution immediately decay, but perturbations beyond some threshold first grow and make long excursions in the phase space before decaying.

Both. I need to show a numerical solution with the given value of $a$ and changing parameters for $\epsilon$.
